# Error comes up when trying to change button background image on tap

Tags: uibutton, swift4, background-image

I'm trying to change button background image by tap. I've looked through several similar topics, but suggested code doesn't work. Could you please specify the reason?

The error is the following:

> ViewController oButton: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var View5: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var oButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func oButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        (oButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: UIControl.State.normal))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer - my mistake was to make an outlet for my button. Having deleted the string "@IBOutlet weak var oButton: UIButton!" resolved the problem